# Unable to View Web Browsing History in Safari 10.0.2 on macOS Sierra

Tags: safari, macos

Safari recently quit displaying my web browsing history. However, it appears to be storing at least part of my history. (See Photo 1 and Photo 2).

Safari preferences specify keeping history for 365 days.

[image: Photo 1: No History Displayed]

[image: Photo 2: Recently Closed History is Being Stored]

What might I try to fix this?

Comment: Go back to your Safari history (that's command + Y) and hit backspace, you're searching for something (online.wsj.com) that's probably not in your history (thus yielding no results). Hitting backspace or canceling the search will remove the 0-result search and show your search history again.

Comment: @owlswipe - Yea, that screenshot was a bit confusing. I had just searched to see if I could find the WSJ site that I knew I had browsed to and which is evident in the "Recently Closed Windows".  Even with the search box blank, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was having other problems with Safari. Since [Apple implemented System Integrity Protection](https://macpaw.com/how-to/how-to-uninstall-safari-on-mac-os-x) with El Capitan, users cannot simply reinstall Safari. Rather, one must reinstall the entire OS.

I chose a Time Machine backup that predated when problems began and reinstalled. The problems have ended. No more unexpected shutdowns of Safari and the history is being recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have the same issue. It started when I upgraded to Sierra, I got Safari 10.0.3. Rather than reinstall all of macOS, I'm waiting to see if this is a bug in syncing between Sierra and iOS through iCloud.

Here are details of my thinking.

Frequently Visited in Favorites isn't showing anything either.

I got a History.db of 61,6 MB in my ~/Library/Safari/ folder and I manage to see some iCloud macbook browsing history on my iPhone running iOS 10.3.1.

[image]

Comment: This problem reoccured when I updated OS. At Apple's suggestion I created a new User Account and the problem disappeared. Conclusion: Something got corrupted in my old User Account. I decided that copying all the files over to the New User Account was simpler than trying to track down the problem in my old account.